# Column x must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

```
SELECT newTable.book_id
FROM (
    SELECT book_id, SUM(stock) AS stock
    FROM editions JOIN stock ON (editions.isbn = stock.isbn)
    GROUP BY book_id

    ) AS newTable
HAVING stock = max(stock);
```

I want this code to produce the book_id of the book with the most of it in stock, i.e. the highest number of copies of the book in stock. I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  column "newtable.book_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 2:  SELECT newTable.book_id
                ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: column "newtable.book_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Any solutions?

PS. Already tried adding `GROUP BY newtable.book_id, newtable.stock` at the end. It generated a syntax error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might consider writing the query as below. You simply order by the column you are aggregating by so the most "in stock" will be at the top and then take X items off the top with the LIMIT clause. In this case, LIMIT 1.

```
SELECT book_id, SUM(stock) AS numstock
FROM editions JOIN stock ON (editions.isbn = stock.isbn)
GROUP BY book_id
ORDER BY numstock desc
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Answers work best if they contain some explanation that can be used by future readers to solve similar problems, rather than unexplained code.